# AngularJs and Jquery error in loaded div content

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, web, development-environment

I'm working in a web, I need to load my div content using this jQuery function:
 $('#mainPage').load($(this).attr('mainContent'));

In my index.php I have configured the directive ng-app=".MyApp" and also I'm using ng-controllers there and it works fine, but using some ng-controllers inside the loaded page in the #mainPage div it doesn't works fine, as a solution I have tryied:

```
angular.element(document).ready(function() {
             angular.bootstrap(document, ['MyApp']);
           });
```

and it loads correctly and then the controller is working fine, but if I load again the div space then Angular crash with the error:

Error: [ng:btstrpd] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.3/ng/btstrpd?p0=....

(that means angular is bootstapped)

I can't load the div's content using ng-includes directive because I shoud use jquery and javascript inside the loaded page, then I don't know how to solve this problem...

Thanks very much!!!

Comment: If you are bootstrapping your application manually then you don't need to use `ng-app=".MyApp"` on page

Comment: why aren't you using angular methodology to load html into view instead of using `$().load()`?

Comment: For the first answer: Also using the bootstrapping manually in the index.html, I can't use the controller in the loaded php file in the #mainPage div
My intention is load authomatically or manually the bootstrap and be able to  use the controller in the loaded php file inside the div

Comment: For the second answer: I can't use the angular methodology to load the php file because inside them I need to use jQuery and javascript libraries, and using angular ng-include, the javascript doesn't works


Thankssss

Comment: I realise that inside the jquery loaded div, I have the angular app MyAdd, but looks like it doesn't have controllers registered